# Why is my logo image not moving horizontally as the page expands?

Tags: css, position, alignment, margin, css-position

The main content of my page (text and a form) move horizontally accross the page as you change the size of the browser window.  My logo stays in a fixed position.  I cannot find a difference in the css between the two classes that would make this happen.  Here is the css:

```
.main {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0 auto; min-width: 1020px; overflow: hidden;}
.header { background:url(images/slider_bgpng200.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; padding:0; margin:0 auto; width: 100%; }
.headertop{width: 44%; background: #d3e5e8; height: 30px; min-width: 1020px;float: left;  padding-left: 50px; margin: 0 auto;}
.block_header {margin:0 auto; width:1200px; padding:0; border:none; }
.space { float:left; padding:0; margin:0; }
.header_text { width:200px; float:right; font:normal 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#9a9a9a; padding:6px 10px 10px 10px; margin:0; text-align:center;}
.slider { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:420px;} 
.slider .gallery { margin:0 auto; width:980px; height:420px; padding:0;} 
.slider .textholder {padding-top: 110px; float: left; width: 44%; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 40px; color: #93a0a2;padding-left: 30px;}
.formbox{float: right; width: 48%; padding-top: 90px; padding-right: 40px;}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="header">
   <div class="headertop"> <img src="images/avidestlogo50perresave.png"  border="0" alt="logo" />
     <div class="header_text"><a href="#">Email</a> | <a href="#">Client Login</a> 
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="block_header">
      <div class="space"><a href="index.html"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class="slider">
         <div class="gallery">
            <div class="textholder">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Where Student and <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alumni Freelancers <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Get Hired
            </div>
            <div class = "formbox">Form is here
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The site is up at avidest.com/schneer so you can see what I am talking about.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A. Why does your header cover everything? B. You header top is floated to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `width:100%` in your `.header` class.

This is not the same as `width:1200px` in your `.block_header` class.

If you want the entire page to centre itself in the same way, I suggest that you wrap the header and the content in an outer `div` that does the centering with a single class

Comment: .block_header does not contain either the logo or the text/form, so would that make a difference?

Comment: I forgot to put a </div> before slider. my mistake.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  It's the `slider` class that has the content, isn't it...  Well, same deal.  You have stated that the width of your header is `100%`, so an auto margin will push its content all the way to the left.  If you want it to move, its width must be less than `100%`.